# How would turning on Read commit snapshot affect Data Queues using WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We're considering turning on *read committed snapshot* isolation level to help with some of our table locking problems.

We have a few stored procedures that use the table hint `WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)` as a [queuing based table setup](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1257/processing-data-queues-in-sql-server-with-readpast-and-updlock/). This prevents multiple worker roles from reading the same row.

I'm a little concerned that the *read committed snapshot* could potentially break the queuing system and more than one worker role could read the same row. Does anyone know if turning on RCS isolation would break this process?

```
WITH  q AS
(
    SELECT TOP Column1
    FROM Table1 c WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
    WHERE c.NextAttemptDate <= GETUTCDATE() 
    ORDER BY c.NextAttemptDate ASC
)
UPDATE  q
SET OperationStatusType = 8
OUTPUT inserted.Column1
```

Comment: You may get a better response over at http://dba.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `UPDATE` takes U-locks on rows of the target table while it checks whether they match your filter or not. After that the lock is either released or converted to an X-lock further down the query pipeline.

It is not possible to affect write locking using locking hints or the isolation level. You are safe. U-locks will be taken.

I'm in the habit of always adding `WITH (UPDLOCK)` redundantly as well so that this behavior is documented in the code.